# Smooth fall in Unity - C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, physics, smoothing

I am working on a Character Controller Script and everything is working fine but the problem is that once my player starts to fall it is so sudden and jerks down. I would like the player to gradually fall down, this is my character controller script -

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float inputDelay = 0.1f;
    public float forwardVel = 12;
    public float rotateCel = 12;
    public float JumpHeight = 20;
    public Vector3 Gravity = new Vector3 (0, -180, 0);
    public bool CanPress;
    private float jumpTime;
    public float _initialJumpTime = 0.4f;
    //[HideInInspector]
    public bool isGrounded;
    Quaternion targetRotation;
    Rigidbody rBody;
    Vector3 forwardInput, turnInput;
    public bool HasJumped;

    public Quaternion TargetRotation
    {
        get {return targetRotation;}
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Physics.gravity = Gravity;
        targetRotation = transform.rotation;
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody> ())
            rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        else {
            Debug.LogError("Character Needs Rigidbody");
        }

    //  forwardInput = turnInput = 0;
        forwardInput = turnInput = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        GetInput ();
        //Turn ();

        if (CanPress == true) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) { 
                HasJumped = true;
                jumpTime = _initialJumpTime;
            }
        }

        if (HasJumped == true) {
            rBody.useGravity = false;
            jumpTime -= 1 * Time.deltaTime;
            if (jumpTime > 0) {
            Jump();
            }
            else {
                HasJumped = false;
                rBody.useGravity = true;
            }
        }
    }


    void GetInput() {
        //forwardInput = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        //turnInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        forwardInput = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotateCel, 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * forwardVel);
        forwardInput = transform.TransformDirection (forwardInput);
        if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.Space)) {
            //HasJumped = false;
        }


    }

    void Jump() { 

            Vector3 up = transform.TransformDirection (Vector3.up);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (up * 5, ForceMode.Impulse);

    }
    void FixedUpdate() {

        Run ();
    }
    void Run() {
        if (Mathf.Abs (10) > inputDelay) {
            //Move
            //rBody.velocity = transform.forward * forwardInput * forwardVel;
            rBody.velocity = forwardInput;
        } else {
            //zero velocity
            rBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;

        }

    }
    void Turn() {
    //  targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotateCel * turnInput * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
    //  transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
        isGrounded = true;
        CanPress = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) {
        isGrounded = false;
        CanPress = false;
    }

}
```

My character has a Rigidbody attactches which uses gravity and has X,Y,Z constraints for Rotation.

- The player goes up smoothly and falls down smoothly but the transition between the two is very abrupt and sudden.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Are you building your own character controller? If you are I am curious as to why you are not using the built in character controller as part of the Unity Standard Assets, which does this all for you :-)

Comment: Hey @Tom, I am doing all of this as part of a learning experience as I dont want to use unity's inbuilt scripts all the time, and creating my own script gives me the options to change the script to suit my games needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I took your code and had a play.

I think the issue was that in your `Run()` function, you were altering the velocity of the `rigidbody` which was affecting your jumping.

I've taken that stuff out and improved your script slightly and tested it. Attach this to a capsule with a `rigidbody` on it, with a floor underneath with a `box collider` on and hit space, and you should get a smooth jump.

Your new(ish) script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float inputDelay = 0.1f;
    public float forwardVel = 12;
    public float rotateCel = 12;
    public float jumpHeight = 10;
    private float jumpTime;
    public float _initialJumpTime = 0.4f;
    //[HideInInspector]
    public bool isGrounded;
    Quaternion targetRotation;
    Rigidbody rBody;
    Vector3 forwardInput, turnInput;
    public bool canJump;

    public Quaternion TargetRotation
    {
        get { return targetRotation; }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        targetRotation = transform.rotation;
        if (GetComponent<Rigidbody>())
            rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Character Needs Rigidbody");
        }

        //  forwardInput = turnInput = 0;
        forwardInput = turnInput = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetInput();
        //Turn ();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && canJump)
        {
            rBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }


    void GetInput()
    {
        //forwardInput = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
        //turnInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        forwardInput = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateCel, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * forwardVel);
        forwardInput = transform.TransformDirection(forwardInput);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Run();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        //HERE YOU SET THE RIGIDBODYS VELOCITY, WHICH IS CAUSING YOUR JUMP TO NOT WORK PROPERLY. DO NOT MODIFY THE VELOCITY
        //OF A RIGIDBODY
        if (Mathf.Abs(10) > inputDelay)
        {
            //Move
            //rBody.velocity = transform.forward * forwardInput * forwardVel;
            rBody.velocity = forwardInput;
        }
        else
        {
            //zero velocity
            rBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }

    void Turn()
    {
        //  targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotateCel * turnInput * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
        //  transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        canJump = true;
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        canJump = false;
    }
}
```

**Couple of points:**

- name your variables inThisKindOfFashion (`jumpHeight`, `isOnGround`, `camelCaseExample`), having variables beginning with a capital letter like `Gravity` and `JumpHeight` can get confusing.
- as someone once answered on one of my questions, don't modify the velocity of a rigidbody unless you know what you are doing! Seems odd, but after following that advice I've never had a problem since!
- In your script I have used `OnCollision` rather than `OnTrigger`. If you put a floor with a `box collider` underneath your `capsule` with a `collider`, `rigidbody` and this script on, your character will stop on the ground. If you use a trigger, he will fall through (at least in my experience!)

Happy coding! :-)

---

**Edit**
To respond to your comments:

*"How do you suggest I move the player"*

Movement can be done in a variety of different ways, but I usually use this one all the time unless I need to do something a bit differently:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime; //speed could be 5f, for example (f means float);
    }

    // then do the same for other directions, RightArrow -.right, UpArrow - .forward, DownArrow - .back
}
```

*"How do I adjust how fast the player jumps"*

You can alter the `jumpHeight` variable for a higher or smaller jump. If by faster you mean falls down faster, go to Edit>Project Settings>Physics> and change Y gravity to something smaller, such as -20.

**Tutorials** can be found [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials)

They have a wide variety of tutorials, and even have ones that come with example projects so you can just put it together following the video.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Tom, I will take that advice into mind :) I will test the code and tell you if it works. :)

Comment: Hey @Tom the jump works great now. just a few questions - How do you suggest I move the player instead with Rigidbody or just using Vector3.Lerp?  How do I adjust how fast the player jumps, and since I am only 13 and dont have much experience in coding is there any website or tutorial that teaches C# coding in detail? Thank you very much for your time and help. Happy Coding to you to! :D

Comment: Thank you very much this answered all of my questions. Big change going from Objective-C to C#. :D                  I dont know if you have heard of the website Ray Wenderlich - but this is my tutorial there - https://www.raywenderlich.com/94649/sprite-kit-kids-swift  Thanks for the help. :D